# listSupportedLanguages() function throws an exception

Tags: java, android, google-translate, google-translation-api

I am using Google Translation API 2.11.0 and trying to get supported languages with listSupportedLanguages() which throws the following exception for some of the languages, including, for example, Bambara ('bm').

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
GET https://translation.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2/languages?target=bm
{
  "code" : 400,
  "details" : [ {
    "@type" : "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
    "fieldViolations" : [ {
      "field" : "target",
      "description" : "Target language: bm"
    } ]
  } ],
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Target language is invalid.",
    "reason" : "badRequest"
  } ],
  "message" : "Target language is invalid.",
  "status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
```

Here's my code calling this function:

```
// import com.google.cloud.translate.*;
// Translate translate = TranslateOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();

 List<Language> languages = translate.listSupportedLanguages(
         Translate.LanguageListOption.targetLanguage("bm"));
```

Has anyone encountered this issue?
It seems that all the languages from the following list should be returned (https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/languages)
My guess is that it's related to the newly added supported languages (https://blog.google/products/translate/24-new-languages/). However not of the new languages causes this error.